# How to configure Kafka in Docker to avoid PolicyViolationException for delete records

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I'm using https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka as a dev environment. However, when I use

```
kafka-delete-records --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --offset-json-file tmp16523977715454317626.json
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Executing records delete operation
Records delete operation completed:
partition: market.ledger-2      error: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.PolicyViolationException: Request parameters do not satisfy the configured policy.
```

This is my current `docker-compose.yml` entry for kafka. I've set `KAFKA_CFG_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE` as advised on a couple of pages but still am getting this error. I think it's something obvious and would like to get some help.

```
  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:2.3.1'
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    environment:
      KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: 'yes'
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS: 'INTERNAL://:29092,EXTERNAL://:9092'
      KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'INTERNAL://kafka:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092'
      KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_CFG_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: 'true'
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```

Answer (score 0):

Topics with `compact` deletion policy don't work, see: https://github.com/provectus/kafka-ui/issues/992

I recommend deleting and re-creating the topics.